# Is there any bullet or other shape indicating question that I can use in Beamer instead of the word question?

Tags: beamer, shapes, bullets

Is there any shape or bullet that indicate on question? It can be something like the shape of a question mark. I want to use it instead of the word question when I want to introduce a question like below.

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
]{beamer}


\usetheme{Darmstadt}        

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{4pt}{5pt}\selectfont}


\begin{document}

\section{Descriptive Outline 1}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\colorbox{red}{Question} Is there a bullet of shape for question?
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use an ordinary ? or there are several packages, which include special icons to indicate questions.

One example from the `bclogo` package (the size has to be adjusted to fit your taste):

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
]{beamer}

\usepackage{bclogo}


\usetheme{Darmstadt}        

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{4pt}{5pt}\selectfont}


\begin{document}

\section{Descriptive Outline 1}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}

\bcquestion Is there a question?

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's it. Thanks. But should the sign be awry like that?

Comment: @user157323 Yes, it is supposed to look like that. You can use any other ? sign you like.

Comment: What are the commands for other ? signs?

Comment: @user157323 You can use whatever you want, images, symbols from all available fonts, something from http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf ... there are no limits.

Comment: Which package I need for \faQuestionCircle?

Comment: @user157323 maybe it is in `fontawesome5`,  but I did not check